# React: connected HOC with with callback as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, higher-order-components

I have several "dumb" components. I'm trying to make a higher-order component that connects them to a Redux store, and passes in a callback function as a prop. The child components will call this callback function in response to a click event.

I'm struggling with scope. The callback function needs to `setState` and also dispatch a Redux action.

Here's what is not working:

```
//Child Component
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.props.callbackFunc}>Click</button>;
  }
}

//callback function
clickCallback(e){
  this.setState({foo: "bar"});
  this.props.dispatch(
    someReduxAction({boo: "baz"})
  );
}

const WithCallbackChunk = (Comp, callback) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.callback = callback.bind(this);
    }
    render() { return <Comp callbackFunc={callback} {...this.props} />; }
  }
}

   
//connected comp
const ConnectedChunk = function(comp){
  return connect(
    null,
    {someReduxAction}
  )(WithCallbackChunk(comp));
}

const ConnectedCallbackComp = ConnectedChunk(Child);

export { ConnectedCallbackComp }
```

I cannot get the scope correct for both `setState` and `props.dispatch` inside the callback.

Thanks in advance!

**Update / explanation**

Several have asked about the purpose of `WithCallbackChunk`. I'm trying to separate presentation logic from form handling.

My application allows users to build customized forms. There is an editing mode that shows a preview of the form, and each of these "chunks" of the form are the `Child` components in the simplified example above. When that form is published, those Child components (that make up the form) need to become interactive and connected to a Redux store.

I'm trying to keep things DRY by reusing the "dumb" presentation components for the editing *and* the live form contexts (because they're the same). But the form handling is only needed in the live context. It seemed messy for the Child component to have all the Redux actions for both contexts, so I'm trying to figure out how to pass in that functionality via props.

My goal was for the Child components to only define the UI, and then let two different "wrapper" HOC components provide the additional functionality for each respective context. Clearly, I haven't gotten that right. And maybe I'm thinking about this in the wrong way? I welcome feedback or suggestions about a better way to do this.

Another way to summarize this is that I'm struggling with React's one-way data flow. (Information only flows "down" to children.) I'm trying to pass the contextual logic down from the HOC. But the Child component is the only one that knows when to call it (because it defines the UI)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do with `WithCallbackChunk`. `clickCallback` needs to part of a class. Instead of returning connect, you can just define it as `const ConnectedCallbackComp = connect(null, {someReduxAction})(Child)`.

Comment: @Yoshi I just updated the question to try to answer your question. Please let me know if it's still not clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You aren't thinking about it wrong, having smart & dumb components is the right way to go. Even though you have to use a Redux HOC to connect it to the store, the connected parent component should just be a container, so you'll have `Form` and `FormContainer`. So, it's very similar to the pattern you're doing now. The state setter will live in the container and pass down callbacks as props to the Form. HOC are generally for sharing logic across components, especially in a case where the component shouldn't care about the details. A component should know about how it's state is set

Comment: @Yoshi I _think_ I understand what you're saying: I should move all the state logic into the container and just pass the callback  function down to the dumb wrapped component. Is this right? The container will be connected, so it's scope will include `dispatch` and `setState` etc... In other words, the problem is that I'm trying to interact with the wrapped component's state from outside. If the state moves out to the container things get simple... I think I get it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the wrong callback on to the wrapped component. Pass the one bound with the `this` of the inner component versus the one passed to the HOC.

```
const withCallback = (WrappedComponent, callback) => {
  class BaseContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.callback = callback.bind(this);
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          callbackFunc={this.callback} // <-- pass the bound callback to this component
          {...this.props}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  return BaseContainer;
};
```

[image: Edit withCallback Higher Order Component Example]

When composing with redux don't forget to also pass a callback to the `withCallback` HOC.

```
const ConnectedChunk = connect(
  null,
  {someReduxAction}
)(withCallback(comp, callback));
```

Comment: While this works, I don't understand the pattern of passing in a state setter into an HOC. Why not just define the method in the class.

Comment: @Yoshi While I don't disagree with you, that isn't what is asked in the question. I suppose this is seen as some sort of applied DRY-ness on the OP's part, but it's a simple enough error to fix, so why not help them make it work. To say anything otherwise would require more questions and getting more context about the use-case.

Comment: @DrewReese Will this provide access to `dispatch` as well? My callback functions dispatch Redux actions. I believe it gets passed as a prop to the connected component, but I've been having trouble getting it in scope for the callback that gets passed to the Child.

Comment: @emersonthis I don't see why not. `withCallback` returns a component that you are then passing to the `connect` HOC to have more state and dispatch mapped to props. Just need to also pass a callback function to the `withCallback` HOC when composing it.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks! I think I might be over-complicating things with what I'm trying to do. I'm curious if you have thoughts on the idea I'm discussing with Yoshi in the comments under the question.

Comment: @emersonthis I don't understand your use case, but I routinely use `mapStateToProps` to inject *other* props (i.e. derived state, custom functions, etc..) completely unrelated to my state, just because that is how `connect` works. The `connect` HOC always injects a `dispatch` prop the wrapped component can use. You can even internally connect  the `BaseContainer` the HOC is returning to redux, such as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62909234/different-between-hoc-redux-and-redux/62909392#62909392). `BaseContainer` can have internal state and pass update functions as props.

Comment: @emersonthis In your case the weirdness is wanting a dynamic callback passed via props to update the state of a component it's passed versus updating or calling back out to some ancestor component that passed the function. Maybe this is an anti-pattern though I've never seen someone try to do what you're trying. Usually you want your state mutators defined where the state is.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese. I think what you said matches the conclusion I came to in the thread above with Yoshi. I'm also interested by what you said about leveraging `mapStateToProps` to inject other things (unrelated to the store). This was one of my first ideas, but I assumed it was taboo for one reason or another.

Comment: @emersonthis Sure. HOC's are just specialized functions that take a component argument and return *some* augmented/decorated component. I view them as "containers" that add behavior to a component. If you're familiar with the container-component pattern, then it's easy to see how HOC's can also serve as containers. If I'm already using `connect` and I just need to slipstream in a custom/default prop value, it works, it isn't worth creating another composable wrapper component or HOC, otherwise I'll fallback to either passing in the value in the caller or compose with a default prop value.

Comment: @emersonthis Has your issue been sufficiently resolved by answer?

Comment: My issue was actually mostly resolved by the discussion we've been having in the comments. But I accepted your answer to indicate resolution.Thanks for your help.