# different between hoc + redux and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to wrap redux into a react hoc like this

```
const WithUser = WrappedComponent => {
  return class ComponentWithUser extends Component {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</WrappedComponent>
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
  }
}

const composeWithUser = compose(connect(mapStateToProps, null), WithUser)

export default composeWithUser
```

If I going to write code in this way, is there any difference from directly connect redux in a performance way?

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite follow the question about "directly connecting redux in a performance way", but you've essentially two HOC's, redux's `connect` HOC and your new `withUser` HOC. IMO the performance will/should be equivalent for any composition of two HOCs and the component being decorated.

Suggestion though, connect the inner component to the store and return it

```
const withUser = WrappedComponent => {
  class ComponentWithUser extends Component {
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />; // props.children included!
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.user,
  });

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentWithUser);
}

export default withUser;
```

This removes the `compose` step since you've manually composed internally, so there may be some benefit/improvement here but I doubt it's significant.

Go for gold, reduce overhead of class-based component

```
const withUser = WrappedComponent => {
  const ComponentWithUser = props => <WrappedComponent {...props} />;

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.user,
  });

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentWithUser);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what I mean is if I just connect redux with a component that I need to use store directly (without hoc) compare with using hoc with redux as I mentioned above. Is there any effect on web performance?

Comment: @SuppawitSatitsongtam How does one connect a component to redux directly without the `connect` HOC, or `useDispatch`/`useSelector` in the case of hooks? Do you mean directly importing  the store and accessing state, i.e. `store.getState()`?